# Struct to binary

Tags: c

```
typedef struct {
    char name[31];
    float price;
    int in_stock;
} Prod;


int binary(const char* filename, Prod* store){

    char NAME = store->name;

    float PRICE = store->price;

    int STOCK = store->in_stock;


    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    if(fp == NULL){return 1;}


    fwrite(&(NAME), sizeof(NAME), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&(PRICE), sizeof(PRICE), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&(STOCK), sizeof(STOCk), 1, fp);
    return 0;
}
```

My mission is to do binary file from struct. I get the following warning :

> "Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast" at line
>   `NAME = store->name.`

Can you guys tell how this should be done correctly if this code is wrong. Code must return 0 if writing in file was successful and 1 for other situations.

Comment: `char NAME` should be `char *NAME`. You could just write the entire struct at once: `fwrite(store, sizeof(*store), 1, fp);`

Comment: It seems that your initialization `NAME = store->name` is making an integer from a pointer without a cast. Use the correct types instead of incorrect ones. Really, you should be able to spot this bug yourself within 5 seconds of reading the line the compiler pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char* pointer is a pointer to one char, usually the first in a string of characters if you're pointing to a string.

When you create an array, if you assign it to something or pass it to a function it becomes a pointer to the first member in the array. So:

```
char name[31];
char NAME = name;
```

The identifier NAME needs to be a char* pointer. So that's the error you get

> "Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast"

So if you write:

```
char* NAME = store->name;
```

That will work.

But you have another problem.

```
fwrite(&(PRICE), sizeof(PRICE), 1, fp);
fwrite(&(STOCK), sizeof(STOCK), 1, fp);
```

Will write fine, but you can't write a char*, because a char* is just an address to the first char of your string. You will need to do something like:

```
fwrite(NAME, sizeof(char), strlen(NAME), fp);
```

To write the string to your file stream. Then you need to terminate it with:

```
putc(0, fp);
```

You put this null terminating character so when you read the file stream back you know how many bytes to read to get the string back. If you don't want to do it this way, you can allocate a fixed set of bytes for the string if you're sure the string won't overflow this buffer. So:

```
fwrite(NAME, sizeof(char), 32, fp);
```

Now you know when you read back from the file stream that the first 32 bytes are set aside for the string.

So again, fwrite(NAME, sizeof(NAME), 1, fp); does nothing except write an address to the file stream. You need to use one of the two methods I mentioned.

Edit: Or even better, do what Johnny Mopp says, much simpler.